# Crontab - Shell Script

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following command in my crontab:

```
* * * * * root /home/amith/m.sh >dev/null 2>&1
```

where m.sh consists of:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -0 "http://www.google.com" > /home/amith/Desktop/h2
```

but the command in shell script is not executing at all.
Can anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: is `m.sh` executable ? Also I would try with `1 * * * *` instead of all `*`.

Comment: Yes it is executable.Okay I will try with that

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that your script `/home/amith/m.sh` is running correctly!
Your crontab entry is wrong you dont need root before script. Also your redirection to /dev/null is not good you are missing / before dev

You can set env varibale for SHELL in crontab with this

```
crontab -e
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Then add your script:

```
* * * * * /home/amith/m.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * cd /full/path; sh m.sh;
```

First, change the directory into your file location (use `cd`). Then, bash it with `sh` command.
Change `* * * * *` with the time schedule. To run the file every minute `* * * * *` To run every hour (1:00, 2:00, 3:00 and so on) use `00 * * * *` To run everyday at 6 AM use `00 06 * * *` To run the file on 9th March at 6 AM use `00 06 09 03 *` The structure is `minute` `hour` `date` `month` `day of week` If you want to schedule it every Monday at 06 AM use this `00 06 * * 1` See this link http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html